# Creating a postgres sequence grouped per key in a single table

Tags: database, postgresql

Let's say I have a table in postgres (pseudo code is easier)

```
Message:
   id (UUID)
   conversation_id (UUID)
   message_seq_id ????
   content (Text)
```

What I want to do is have the database create a sequence for message_seq_id but grouped by conversation_id

Rather than creating sequences for every single conversation, can I just have a counter that is tied to a specific other column in the same table.

so that rows would look like:

Messages:

```
Message(id='123456', conversation_id = '1', message_seq_id = 1, content 'helloworld')
Message(id='123457', conversation_id = '2', message_seq_id = 1, content 'helloworld')
Message(id='123458', conversation_id = '3', message_seq_id = 1, content 'helloworld')
..........
Message(id='123456', conversation_id = '1', message_seq_id = 2, content 'helloworld')
```

Such that the message_sequence_id auto increments on a "conversation_id" basis only.

I can do it in code, but would be nice if postgres supported it without having to create thousands of separate sequences.

Comment: It's easier to just store a timestamp for each conversation. Then you can easily sort by that and generate the conversation_id on the fly using a window function if you really need it.

Comment: In your sample data the message_seq_id is not incrementing

Comment: Agree with horsey -- unless you need to be able to efficiently find the 10th message for every conversation, it is trivial to just number the messages within each conversation when needed. Otherwise you'll need a serialisation mechanism at the conversation level to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Don't use a sequence for this. If you truly require the message sequence ID you'll need a counter table. Look up "postgresql gapless sequence". I strongly suggest not doing that, and instead generating it on the fly if needed. The only downside there is that it's not stable across `DELETE`s, in that deleting a message will effectively renumber ones after it. soft-delete would solve that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is where I was heading anyway.